# Require following dll . for creating Windows application setup wizard

Tags: .net, dll, installation

I want to create a setup wizard using C#.NET. I am not getting the following DLLs and would like help getting them:

```
UtilityLibrary.Designers.dll
UtilityLibrary.Win32.WindowsAPI.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your bin directory. if it is not there, than get a copy of ddl from GAC as described [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/wellink/archive/2006/07/12/12947.aspx)

Comment: i want it from external resources i dont have my own.Is it available on Net?

Comment: @MAHESH A quick google search reveals this code project article, mentioning the above 2 DLLs. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ak_wizard.aspx